# creation of a N-dimensional matrix with a dictionary - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to know how can I create N size matrix  in which the index of the matrix will be keys from a dictionary .
I'm assuming that python has the option to support this matrix at the very least in case that the values of each key would be logical unsigned int number (or masked into a one)  I will have access to any cell in the matrix
by using dict[key] instead of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Following example should help, it creates a 2 dimensional matrix of size 2 × 3:

```
d = {
    0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
    1: {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f'},
}
from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)

# Using keys as indices
print d[1][2]

# output
{0: {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 1: {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'f'}}
f
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I would do it :

```
def showMatrixForm(matrix):
    matshape=""
    for row in range(1,matrix["rows"]+1):
        for column in range(1,matrix["columns"]+1):
            spaces=5-len(str(matrix[str(row)+","+str(column)]))
            matshape+="".join([" " for space in range(spaces)])+str(matrix[str(row)+","+str(column)])
        matshape+="\n"
    return matshape



matrix={}

rows=10
columns=10

matrix["rows"]=rows
matrix["columns"]=columns

i=0
for row in range(1,rows+1):
    for column in range(1,columns+1):
        i+=1
        matrix[str(row)+","+str(column)]=i

print(showMatrixForm(matrix))
'''
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30
   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40
   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50
   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60
   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70
   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80
   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90
   91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100
'''

print(matrix["1,2"],matrix["8,4"],matrix["5,7"])
'''
(2, 74, 47)
'''
```

I hope this will help you.